# "Unexpected tokens" error in function call

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having some trouble with Kotlin syntax, it requires a semicolon inside a function call (?!).

I was simply attempting to convert the code from AltBeacon website, the one used to get coarse location [permissions](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html). Here's what I've come up with on a rush:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    val TAG = "MAIN_ACTIVITY"
    val PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1


    override fun  onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                val  builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setTitle("This app needs location access")
                builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons.")
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                builder.setOnDismissListener {
                    val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION) 
                }
                builder.show()

            }
        }

    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,  grantResults: IntArray) {
            when (requestCode) {
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION-> {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission granted")
                } else {
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited")
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                    builder.setOnDismissListener { }
                    builder.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Compiler has issues with this line:

```
requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION)
```

```
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
```

Comment: Everything is fine with your code. Maybe Android Studio got to some inconsistent state, did you try to restart it?

Comment: @dhabensky 'Invalidate caches and restart', then 'Clean project', 'Rebuild project' - still, the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is ok with kotlin syntax here.
The problem is that you have a strange invisible symbol at the end of that line. I pasted that code in notepad++ and saw this: [image]
So just delete it and compilation will succeed.